# YouTube video and Image in a single ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, android-sliding

I need to make a slider which could possibly contain a YouTube video, an image, and a gif.

I can make a slider of an image or a gif, but how can I merge them all in single ViewPager. Please help. Any suggestions or links would be helpful.

Comment: Make separate fragments for each viewpager-item. load images in 1st 2 fragments, a YouTube video in 3rd one and GIF in the last one..

Comment: Just create a fragment per page, and use a FragmentPagerAdapter to show different fragments in a single ViewPager

Comment: Creating Fragment is not a solution for me because the contents of ViewPager is dynamic. It can contain 50 of images and video. So according to you I will have to create different fragment for different images and video. Like 50... It's not the solution I am looking for. Although thank You for your response.

Comment: you can use Recyclerview having 3 view types image video and gif with LinearLayoutManager having horizontal scroll type .. FOLLOW THE KISS (keep it simple stupid) PRINCIPLE :P dont mind J.K

Comment: With above solution, what I can do is that there will be like 30 images straight then let's say 20 videos. But I don't want them separate, I want them mixed. Like random sometimes images come some time videos.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that your fragments will be in fixed positions in your ViewPager..
You should make two Fragments with two different layouts
let's call them: `ImageFragment` and `VideoFragment`.
you should also extend `FragmentPagerAdapter`
and implement `getItem(int position)` like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 2)
        return VideoFragment.newInstance();
    return ImageFragment.newInstance();
}
```

**EDIT:**
So this time we'll suppose that you have many images and one video at the end of the ViewPager..
so you can put the paths of images in `ArrayList<String>` (maybe local paths or remote paths from server), and put video path in a String variable as well.. and pass each of these strings to the appropriate fragments like this:

```
    public class MultiMediaAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<String> paths;
        private String videoPath;

        public MultiMediaAdapter (FragmentManager fm, List<String> paths, String videoPath) {
            super(fm);
            this.paths = paths;
            this.videoPath = videoPath;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
//pay attintion that position starts  counting from zero
            if (position == paths.size()) //video at the end of the ViewPager
                return VideoFragment.newInstance(videoPath);
            return ImageFragment.newInstance(paths.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.paths.size()+1; //+1 for the video
        }
    }
```

and you should load each image in the fragment like this:

```
 public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
        private String path;

        public static ImageFragment newInstance(String path){
            ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
            fragment.setPath(path);

            return fragment;
        }

        private void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            if (path != null){
              // and here load image into imageView using path, the way you want
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

and VideoFragment will be just as similar to ImageFragment

Comment: Creating Fragment won't help. Because my ViewPager can contains 50 of images or video. It is dynamic actually. So creating so much fragment will not be good for my solution.